How to create custom Pydantic type for Python's "ElementTree"
I want to create a custom Pydantic type for Python's ElementTree. It should accept string as input and type to parse the XML string via ElementTree.fromstring and raise appropriate error is invalid XML is found.
I tried creating a custom type using pydantic Annotated method but got an error saying ElementTree.Element does not define __get_pydantic_core_schema__.

I could not find much resources regarding this. So this is how I proceeded and it is working quite well.
First create an _ElementTreeAnnotation:
import xml.etree.ElementTree as _ET
from typing import Annotated, Any, Optional

from defusedxml.ElementTree import fromstring, tostring
from pydantic import GetCoreSchemaHandler
from pydantic_core import core_schema

class _ElementTreeAnnotation:
    @classmethod
    def validate_value(cls, value: str) -> _ET.Element:
        """
        Validates input value; if it's a string, it tries to parse it as XML
        """
        try:
            tree = fromstring(value)
        except (_ET.ParseError, ValueError):
            raise ValueError("Invalid XML: cannot parse")

        return tree

    @classmethod
    def serialize(cls, instance: _ET.Element) -> str:
        """
        Serializes an ET.Element instance to an XML string.
        """
        return tostring(instance, encoding="unicode")

    @classmethod
    def _discriminator(cls, v: Any) -> Optional[str]:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return "from_str"

        if isinstance(v, _ET.Element):
            return "from_instance"

        return None

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls,
        _source_type: Any,
        _handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler,
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        """
        Defines a Pydantic core schema for XML element validation and serialization.
        We return a pydantic_core.CoreSchema that behaves in the following ways:

        * `str` will be parsed as `etree.Element` instances
        * `etree.Element` instances will be parsed as `etree.Element` instances without any changes
        * Nothing else will pass validation
        * Serialization will always return just return string representation of `etree.Element`
        """

        # schema for validating a string and converting it to an ElementTree element
        from_str_schema = core_schema.chain_schema(
            [
                core_schema.str_schema(),
                core_schema.no_info_plain_validator_function(cls.validate_value),
            ]
        )

        # json schema: always use "from_str_schema"
        # python schema: use discriminated unions
        # tagged unions: ElementTree type is returned as it is while for string types "from_str_schema" is used
        # for any other data type custom error "invalid_union_tag" is raised
        # serialization: serialize ElementTree object to string
        return core_schema.json_or_python_schema(
            json_schema=from_str_schema,
            python_schema=core_schema.tagged_union_schema(
                choices={
                    "from_instance": core_schema.is_instance_schema(_ET.Element),
                    "from_str": from_str_schema
                },
                discriminator=cls._discriminator,
                custom_error_type="invalid_union_tag",
                custom_error_message="Unable to extract union tag using discriminator",
                custom_error_context={
                    "discriminator": "String or etree.Element"
                }
            ),
            serialization=core_schema.plain_serializer_function_ser_schema(cls.serialize)
        )


Then create a custom pydantic type:
# create custom pydantic type for python's ElementTree.Element
XmlElement = Annotated[
    _ET.Element, _ElementTreeAnnotation
]

Now you can use it like this:
class FooBar(BaseModel):
    response_xml: XmlElement = Field(description="Response XML")

I have added comments to explain what each line is doing. The gist of it is:

str will be parsed as etree.Element instances.
etree.Element instances will be parsed as etree.Element instances without any changes.
Nothing else will pass validation. It will raise a pydantic custom error with type invalid_union_tag.
Serialization will always return string representation of etree.Element.

Notes:

I am using defusedxml package to parse untrusted XML.

References:

https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/json_schema/#skipjsonschema-annotation
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/types/#handling-third-party-types
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/unions/#discriminated-unions

